# Bootstrap 3 Dropdown not expanding

Tags: css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I’m trying to retro fit Bootstrap into an existing Asp.Net Web Forms project and I’m not able to get a dropdown to expand and show.

I went to NuGet and then added BootStrap 3.3.6 which is what was the default. I then downloaded the Cerulean .css files off of Bootswatch.com and replaced the bootstrap.css and bootstrap.min.css files in the Content folder.  From there I copied there sample Nav and put it on the page.

The Nav bar initially looks correct with the Cerulean theme but when I tried to expand the dropdown list nothing happened. I’m going to try to use the dropdown lists for my menu so I’m trying to get that to work.

I initially had the reference to the .js files at the bottom of the page. I have since moved them to the top of the page to see if that made any difference but it didn’t.

Anyone know what I might be missing to get Bootstrap’s dropdown to work?

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site.master.cs" Inherits="PrefBid.Site" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>PBS</title>
    <script src="Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/respond.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<link href="Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" />  

    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">PBS</a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="#">Dashboard</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Management</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Reports</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container body-content">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>

    </form>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Check the paths to the jQuery and Bootstrap js files

Comment: You have `bootstrap.min.js` before `jquery-2.1.4.min.js`, jQuery needs to before Bootstraps JS file.

Comment: @vanburen...that was it. Thanks! You should put that as an answer so I can mark it for you.

Comment: I knew the order of the .css files made a difference and should have realized the .js files would have as well. With that being said, shouldn't the .js files be put at the bottom of the page? Or, is that only for custom .js code? I guess having the jquery.js files at the top would allow them to be available as soon as the page is loaded so that's probably where they belong.